# Running a Batch (which run an exe) from ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, batch-file, asp.net-2.0, impersonation

I have the following code inside an ASP .NET 2.0 webapp, which call an external bat:

```
using (Process process = new Process()) 
{
    process.StartInfo.FileName = command;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
    process.Start();

    process.WaitForExit();
    int exitCode = process.ExitCode;
}
```

This code works fine and the batch script is successfully executed.

If i try to call an external executable (no matter what the exe does) from inside the batch script, I got an error related to user privileges (unfortunately I have not the full error message, but it looks like that the ASP .NET User cannot run the executable.

I have tried to specify this parameter in order to use a specified user:

```
process.StartInfo.UserName = "User";
process.StartInfo.Password = this.ConvertToSecureString("Password");
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

but the process just hangs forever.

Comment: Are you using a User under Active Directory?

Comment: @Daniele No, it's all in a local server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158#4) old article from Microsoft, it describe a way to use the Windows API, for impersonation purpose, in ASP.NET, don't be afraid about the spaghetti code you will see, just implement your call inside the:

```
public void Page_Load(Object s, EventArgs e)
{
    if(impersonateValidUser("username", "domain", "password"))
    {
        //Insert your code that runs under the security context of a specific user here.
        undoImpersonation();
    }
    else
    {
        //Your impersonation failed. Therefore, include a fail-safe mechanism here.
    }
}
```